# System arraycopy and append files

Tags: java, arrays, file, copy, byte

I have a problem.

Is there an ability to create a file txt as 8 bytes from these?

```
byte[] bk1;
bk1=readBytesFromFile("Z:\\secretkey.txt"); // contain - aa
byte[] bk;
bk=readBytesFromFile("Z:\\wIV.txt"); // contain - 123456789
        
byte[] out = new byte [bk.length + bk1.length];
System.arraycopy(bk, 2, out, 4, bk1.length);
//out.length = 8; - not working
saveBytesToFile("Z:\\IVsk.txt", out);
```

I would like to connect bk with bk1. Open bk, paste content of bk1 on 2 - 4 position - something like this: `12aa4567` or `12aa3456` - I need this file 8 bytes and save this to IVsk.txt

Comment: Was this question deleted and reposted? I'm reasonably sure I saw it an hour ago and left a comment.

Comment: Also if you only want 8 bytes then allocate the array for 8 bytes `byte[] out = new byte[8]`. The second and fourth arguments of arraycopy also refer to where you want to copy from and to in the arrays. You can find additional documentation [on the api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

Comment: @Locke but I would like to connect these files as well, not only allocate them on 8 bytes. my IVsk.txt looks like this now: ```    ĺp—    ```

Comment: @Locke I used it and now I have mistakes. and I would like to now a correct implementation to my files.

Comment: So you want to insert one byte array into the middle of another and take the first 8 bytes of the result?

Comment: @Locke exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are jut having a hard time figuring out what arguments to pass to `System::arraycopy`. You can always consult the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for additional details. That being said, here is a quick example with your use case where the arrays `a` an `b` are merged together.

```java
// Inputs to merge
byte[] a = "abcdefghij".getBytes();
byte[] b = "0123456789".getBytes();

// Output array
byte[] out = new byte [8];
```

You can overlap the two arrays by first filling out with the first array and then replacing the specific elements from the second array.

```java
// Fill out with the first few elements of a
System.arraycopy(a, 0, out, 0, out.length);
// Out now has value: "abcdefgh"

// Replace 2 elements starting from index 2 of out with bk 
System.arraycopy(b, 0, out, 2, 2);
// Out now has value: "ab01efgh"
```

Based on your question you could also do an additional copy to make sure no elements are overwritten.

```java
// Fill out with the first few elements of a
System.arraycopy(a, 0, out, 0, 2);
// Out now has value: "ab------" ('-' represents 0 in array)

// Replace 2 elements starting from index 2 of out with b 
System.arraycopy(b, 0, out, 2, 2);
// Out now has value: "ab01----" ('-' represents 0 in array)

// Fill remainder with remaining elements of a 
System.arraycopy(a, 2, out, 4, 4);
// Out now has value: "ab01cdef"
```

Comment: Is there an option, using your last example, change it again to "abcdefgh"?